# How to avoid page reload in php form submission

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I am currently using php in my html page and there is an action in the same page which gets executed upon form submission. Currently whole form gets reloaded while I want the php action to be run in the background with out reloading. How do I do it. I would also want to clear the text box after submit button is clicked. Following is the code I am currently using

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="index.php" method="post"  role="form">
        <input type="email" placeholder="Enter email"  name="email_address">
        <button class="btn btn-primary custom-button red-btn">Sign Up</button>
    </form>

<?php



if(isset($_POST['email_address'])  !(trim($_POST['email_address']) == ''))

// do some action
}

?>
</body>

</html>
```

Note: Following code worked for me

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#contactForm').submit(function () {
       $.post("mailer.php",$("#contactForm").serialize(), function(data){
       });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You should redirect user to other page like thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use AJAX for this, for without reloading. Or, if you want to do it without disturbing the page, you need to set `target`.

#### Using AJAX

```
$("form").submit(function(){
  $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize());
  return false;
});
```

#### Using `target`

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" role="form" target="_blank">
```

Comment: I would use `return false;` cautiously - typically preferring `e.preventDefault()` because returning false will also stop event propagation, might affect other functions if you rely on event bubbling.

Comment: $('#contactForm').submit(function () {
       $.post("mailer.php",$("#contactForm").serialize(), function(data){
       });
   return false;
 }); worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Using ajax

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="myform"><!--changge-->
        <input type="email" placeholder="Enter email"  name="email_address">
        <button class="btn btn-primary custom-button red-btn" id="signup">Sign Up</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#signup').click(function()
    {
         $.ajax({
          url:'index.php',
          method:'post',
          data : $('#myform').serialize(),
          success:function()
         {
         } 

    )};
    );
    });
</script>
```

Comment: it gave me syntax error while this worked $.post("mailer.php",$("#contactForm").serialize(), function(data){
       });

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="myform" action="index.php"><!--changge-->
        <input type="email" placeholder="Enter email"  name="email_address">
        <button class="btn btn-primary custom-button red-btn" id="signup">
         Sign Up</button>
    </form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#signup').click(function(){
        $.post($(this).attr("action"), $("#myform").serialize(),function(response){
            alert(response) // you can get the success response return by php after submission success
        });
    )};
});
```