# How to prevent page from reloading after form submit - JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I am working on a website for my app development class and I have the weirdest issue.

I am using a bit of JQuery to send form data to a php page called 'process.php, and then upload it to my DB. The weird bug is that the page reloads upon submitting the form, and I cannot or the life of me figure out how to make the JQuery go on in just the background. That is sorta of the point of using JQuery in the first place haha. Anyways, I will submit all relevant code, let me know if you need anything else.

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#button').click(function () {

    var name = $("#name").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();

    $.post("process.php", {
      name: name,
      email: email
    }).complete(function() {
        console.log("Success");
      });
  });
});
</script>
<div class= "main col-xs-9 well">
  <h2 style="color: black" class="featurette-heading">Join our mailing list!</h2>
  <form id="main" method = "post" class="form-inline">
    <label for="inlineFormInput">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0" id="inlineFormInput" placeholder="Jane Doe">
    <label for="inlineFormInputGroup">Email</label>
    <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
      <input type="text" id="email" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroup" placeholder="janedoe@email.com">
    </div>
    <!--Plan to write success message here -->
    <label id="success_message"style="color: darkred"></label>
    <button id ="button" type="submit" value="send" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

This is my php if its relevant:

```
<?php
  include 'connection.php';

  $Name = $_POST['name'];
  $Email = $_POST['email'];

  //Send Scores from Player 1 to Database 
  $save1   = "INSERT INTO `contact_list` (`name`, `email`) VALUES ('$Name', '$Email')";

  $success = $mysqli->query($save1);

  if (!$success) {
    die("Couldn't enter data: ".$mysqli->error);

    echo "unsuccessfully";
  }

  echo "successfully";
?>
```

This is a screenshot of the log:

[image: screenshot of log]

Comment: then just replace `type="submit"` with `type="button"`, as you are using AJAX. No need to have submit type

Comment: Try changing the input type of your button from `submit` to `button`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid page reload in php form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23196423/how-to-avoid-page-reload-in-php-form-submission)

Comment: Add event into your function parameter, and then inside that function event.preventDefault()

Comment: Side note: You've a serious sql injection hole.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks for the edit lol, also yes I know that! This isn't a live website and I have been told to pursue mysqli and PDO in the future to be safe. If this wasn't a time sensitive project I would be doing it on this one. Thank you though!

Comment: You're welcome @Casey.PhillipsTMC

Comment: @JigarShah that was the one!!! All this time spent troubleshooting and that's all it was! Thank you!

Comment: @JustBaron you as well man! Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent page reload and redirect on form submit ajax/jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26567486/prevent-page-reload-and-redirect-on-form-submit-ajax-jquery)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Submit form without page reloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866063/submit-form-without-page-reloading)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The `<button>` element, when placed in a form, will submit the form automatically unless otherwise specified. You can use the following 2 strategies:

1. Use `<button type="button">` to override default submission behavior
2. Use `event.preventDefault()` in the onSubmit event to prevent form submission

### Solution 1:

- Advantage: simple change to markup
- Disadvantage: subverts default form behavior, especially when JS is disabled. What if the user wants to hit "enter" to submit?

Insert extra `type` attribute to your button markup:

```
<button id="button" type="button" value="send" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

### Solution 2:

- Advantage: form will work even when JS is disabled, and respects standard form UI/UX such that at least one button is used for submission

Prevent default form submission when button is clicked. Note that this is **not the ideal solution because you should be in fact listening to the submit event, not the button click event**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  // Listen to click event on the submit button
  $('#button').click(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var name = $("#name").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();

    $.post("process.php", {
      name: name,
      email: email
    }).complete(function() {
        console.log("Success");
      });
  });
});
```

#### Better variant:

In this improvement, we listen to the submit event emitted from the `<form>` element:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  // Listen to submit event on the <form> itself!
  $('#main').submit(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var name = $("#name").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();

    $.post("process.php", {
      name: name,
      email: email
    }).complete(function() {
        console.log("Success");
      });
  });
});
```

#### Even better variant: use [`.serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) to serialize your form, but remember to add `name` attributes to your input:

The `name` attribute is required for `.serialize()` to work, as per [jQuery's documentation](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/):

> For a form element's value to be included in the serialized string, the element must have a name attribute.

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0" id="inlineFormInput" placeholder="Jane Doe">
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroup" placeholder="janedoe@email.com">
```

And then in your JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  // Listen to submit event on the <form> itself!
  $('#main').submit(function (e) {

    // Prevent form submission which refreshes page
    e.preventDefault();

    // Serialize data
    var formData = $(this).serialize();

    // Make AJAX request
    $.post("process.php", formData).complete(function() {
      console.log("Success");
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Use #2 if want form to submit using keyboard

Comment: @charlietfl You are correct: in terms of user accessibility,  solution #2 is the way to go ;) also updated answer for a better solution, i.e. listening to submit event instead of button click.

Comment: @Terry by far one of the most helpful answers I have ever gotten on here. I am teaching the class to myself as a Directed Study so this is more than helpful, to be honest! I have seen a lot of this stuff out there in my google searches but never explained this well! Thank you!

Comment: @Terry seriously man...you're a life saver!!! I spent literally 6hrs trying so many different things (including other stackoverflow suggestions). I was almost about to give up and cry (metaphorically). I am sooooo glad you're solution worked. I will buy you a few drinks if we ever bump into each other.

Comment: @Terry I really wanted the form and submit type button because a submit type button prompts for required fields. So while solution 1 didn't work, solution 2 worked like a charm. Again, drinks and lunch on me!!!

Answer (score 0):

clear the previous state when loading the page.... add this to document.ready function.

```
if ( window.history.replaceState ) {
    window.history.replaceState( null, null, window.location.href );
}
```