# Prevent form submit from refreshing page without jQuery preventDefault?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML form and I'm saving the form data to an XML file using PHP.

Upon submission, the page automatically refreshes - this is the default behaviour.
I want to disable this, but using jQuery preventDefault also prevents saving the data.

How can I prevent it from refreshing the page, while maintaining the form functionality? Thanks.

Comment: You have the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45634088/how-to-prevent-page-from-reloading-after-form-submit-jquery/45634140

Comment: One was is, you can override the submit preventing default and use jquery ajax to manually post the data.  Code examples of what you have now would help

Comment: try making the `<button type="submit">` to `<button type="button">`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this using an AJAX request, saving the form data to a JSON object, and then into a file.  Thanks for your answers!