# Web page refreshes itself after I clicked a button. How could I avoid it?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently learning the JS basics, and the sample code acts weird. When I press the button the two numbers from input "ar1" and "ar2" supposed to be added up, and displayed in the paragraph. For a moment I see the answer, but the webpage refreshes itself immediatly. What could cause it?
Thanks for your answer!

```
...
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="number" name="ar1"></br>
            <input type="number" name="ar2"></br>
            <button>go</button>
        </form>
        <p id="osszeg">Here is the answer</p>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The script.js:

```
function osszead()
{
    let ar1 = parseInt(document.querySelector("input[name=ar1]").value);
    let ar2 = parseInt(document.querySelector("input[name=ar2]").value);

    let ossz = ar1 + ar2;

    document.querySelector("#osszeg").innerHTML = ossz;

}
```

Comment: see this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45634088/how-to-prevent-page-from-reloading-after-form-submit-jquery/45634140

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change your button type to "button" and put event onclick="osszead()". By default html button type is "submit" and as a default behaviour, clicking submit button submit it's data to it's action url.

```
<button type="button" onclick="osszead()">go</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the button has a default `type` of `submit` because it's inside a `<form>`, which causes it to submit the form, effectively reloading the page.

You can either:

- Not use any `<form>` at all:

  ```html
  <body>

      <input type="number" name="ar1"></br>
      <input type="number" name="ar2"></br>
      <button id="go-button">go</button>

      <p id="osszeg">Here is the answer</p>

      [...]
  ```
- Set the `button` type explicitly:

  ```html
  <body>
      <form>
          <input type="number" name="ar1"></br>
          <input type="number" name="ar2"></br>
          <button id="go-button" type="button">go</button>
      </form>
      <p id="osszeg">Here is the answer</p>
  ```

Note that I added an `id` to the button, because you also need to add a `click` event listener. Add this to the end of your JavaScript code:

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("go-button");
btn.addEventListener("click", osszead);
```

Comment: If one wants to avoid a submit, setting the `button` explicit to `type="submit"` won't solve that. Also, SO is full of answers and when a question can use one of those, you are supposed to _vote/flag to close as a duplicate_, not post an answer.

Comment: Oops! I meant `type="button"`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an onclick event and a type to your button.

```
<button type="button" onclick="osszead()">go</button>
```

Comment: A note: when you edit someone else's post, don't add something like this _Edit: changed on click to onclick & fixed closed button tag_ **into the post itself**, just use the existing "Edit summary" field. The content in that field is available in the post edit history so anyone can read what you did.

Comment: @Ason I wouldn't have added that if there wasn't a 6 character minimum to edits, as the edit I had made was only 2 characters.

Comment: I know the limitations...still, just don't add such stuff to a post.

Answer (score 0):

By default buttons are acting as "submit" type and submit types tend to reload the page. You can prevent the default behaviour using  `function passed(e){e.preventDefault();...}`. `<button type="button" onclick="osszead">go</button>` might also work.