# Avoiding page refresh in PHP with form submission

Tags: php

I am working on the following code in the same PHP page. I am trying to instantly print the values of the form variables as soon as user hits submit button. However, I am seeing page getting refreshed with the following code. What would I need to do if I want to see the values instantly?

```
 <form  id = "myform" action="" method="post">
    First name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="Mickey"><br>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="LastName" value="Mouse"><br>
   <button name = "submittest" type = "submit test">Submit Test </button>
 </form>

<?php 

     if (isset($_POST['submittest'])) {
        $example = $_POST['FirstName'];
        $example2 = $_POST['LastName];
        echo $example . " " . $example2;
    }


?>
```

I have looked at some similar threads and haven't found what I am looking for :

1) [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23507608/form-submission-without-page-refresh) they have suggested Ajax approach. I am trying to avoid it because I am having CORS issue while making ajax call.

2) [Here again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23196423/how-to-avoid-page-reload-in-php-form-submission), ajax and target based approach which will take me to the new tab

3) [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866063/submit-form-without-page-reloading) in addition to Ajax, iFrame approach is suggested but not sure if  that would give me what I am looking for because after getting the values of these variables, I am planning to convert all the values into a JSON object and call a Java webservice using curl. All of this I am doing to avoid javascript as I am encountering CORS issue.

Comment: _instantly print the values of the form variables_ Where are you trying to print these values?

Comment: Here `echo $example . " " . $example2;` ?

Comment: So what does not work about what you have done

Comment: @RiggsFolly To be specific I am developing a plug-in using this software `https://www.i2b2.org/webclient/`.  We have shibboleth based authentication on that website. My php file is inside `webclient` folder. So whenever I try to hit a submit button it just logs me out of that application which I am assuming is happening because of the page refresh after clicking submit button.

Comment: If you submit a form without using Ajax, you're going to have a refresh. This is simply how web sites work.

Comment: @GregSchmidt I see. On the other hand, do you think enabling CORS could be a security threat?

Comment: Nothing about what you've posted so far explains why you would need CORS. You've said something about an assumption you're making about the log out issue. Maybe create a new question to solve that problem instead of trying to add workarounds on top of workarounds?