# PHP SQL QUIZ-TRIVIA,How I can disable refreshing page after submit? not count correct answers because of reloading page after submit

Tags: php

I would like to display count of correct answers, but my page is reloading after submit.Code is comparing data after load, not input data. 
How I should prevent to not refresh/reload page after submit and just display results. I do not want you use Javascript or Jquery

if use [How to avoid page reload in php form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23196423/how-to-avoid-page-reload-in-php-form-submission)
after submit my page, just redirect to new tab, nothing else happen and I will receive new questions and choice to play the game. Looks like there is problem with foreach loop, that it is looping every time submit is processed.

How I can disable refreshing page after submit?

```
<?php
   include "sql.php";
?>

<body>
    <form method="POST" >
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($list as $key=>$value) :?>
        <?php 

        $option = [$value['capitol'], $value['choice1'], $value['choice2']];
        shuffle($option);
        ?>
        <li> <h5>What is capitol city of <?php echo $value['country']."?";?></h5> </li>
            <input type="radio" name="<?=$value['id']?>" value="<?=$option[0]?>" required> <?=$option[0]?>
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="<?=$value['id']?>" value="<?=$option[1]?>" > <?=$option[1]?>
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="<?=$value['id']?>" value="<?=$option[2]?>" > <?=$option[2]?>
            <br>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    </ul>
    <input type="submit" name='submit'>
    </form>
  </body>
  <?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $correct=0;

            foreach($list as $key=>$value){
                $answer = $_POST[$value['id']];

                if($answer == $value['capitol'] ){
                    $correct++;

                }
            }

            echo "Correct answers " .$correct;

        }

    ?>
</html>
```

Comment: Not possible without javascript. The page reload can't be prevented using only PHP.

Comment: @MuhammadTashfeen thanks for answer, what you recommend me to do in this case?

Comment: use javascript like he said.

Comment: Possible duplicate of the question [how to avoid page reload in php form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23196423/how-to-avoid-page-reload-in-php-form-submission)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid page reload in php form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23196423/how-to-avoid-page-reload-in-php-form-submission)

Comment: @NKU you can set a event on submit button to call a javascript function which checks for the answer if it is correct or not. I will share the static version in the answer below. You can adapt it according to your logic.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you will stop the form submit and calculate the result.

```
<form onsubmit="return false">
<input type="radio" name="city" value="toronto"> Toronto<br>
<input type="radio" name="city" value="calgiri"> Calgiri<br>
<button type="submit" onclick="checkAnswer()">Send</button>
</form>

<script>
function checkAnswer() {
    let answer = document.querySelector('input[name=city]:checked').value
    alert(answer);
}
</script>
```

Comment: it does not work, after click on send, there is no response at all :-(